# How to speed up

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, mpu6050, float

I found that using more float variable in arduino uno(atmega328p) slows it down (very muck that i can get slow response)

so, how to speed up it processing ?

my data are euler's angle with 2 digits and 2 decimals like give below

XX.XX , where X is number Eg.(85.63,34.65,etc) (from MPU6050)

How to process it fast?

Comment: Add the code for the slow procedure (or add your whole program) into the question.  Details make differences.  To tell markdown that a section is `code`, highlight it and press ctrl-K

Comment: i just found by multiplying raw value by 100 (85.63 * 100 = 8563),it is still integer so it will be fast in arduino uno. And divide it by 100 to get processed value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A technique commonly used in digital signal processing is using [fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) instead of [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).  In fixed-point arithmetic, one calculates using numbers multiplied by some power of two or ten, and in effect mentally positions a binary or decimal point several bits or digits up while calculating. [Numerical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis#Generation_and_propagation_of_errors) may be needed to determine if the arithmetic is accurate enough and whether numbers will stay in bounds, or overflow.

The question doesn't say what's being calculated; it's possible fixed-point arithmetic might work, or might not.  A short self-contained fixed-point calculation that starts with MPU6050 sensor readings is likely to be ok, but long-term calculations (eg, integration of accelerations to get velocities and positions) that let error accumulate without reset may go too far astray.  In such a case, numerical analysis can indicate what intermediate results need to be stored most accurately.

Typically, when slow code is posted someone can point out speedups, from a few percent up to dozens of times faster.  Changes may range from adding or removing parentheses or temporary variables, to refactoring, to substitution of a new algorithm.

Comment: yeah i am now modifying code .